# A macro highlighted as keyword: pascal

Tags: objective-c, c, macos, macos-carbon

While looking in the sample code for [FunkyOverlayWindow](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#samplecode/FunkyOverlayWindow/Introduction/Intro.html), I just found a pretty interesting declaration:

```
pascal OSStatus MyHotKeyHandler(
    EventHandlerCallRef nextHandler,
    EventRef theEvent,
    void *userData
);
```

Here, `pascal` is highlighted as a keyword (pink in standard Xcode color scheme). But I just found it's a macro, interestingly enough defined in file CarbonCore/ConditionalMacros.h as:

```
#define pascal
```

So, what is (or was) it supposed to do? Maybe it had some special use in the past?

While this discussion might not be well suited here, it would be interesting to know why Apple still using Carbon if this relates to the answer. I have no experience in Carbon, but this code appears to set a keyboard event handler which makes me wonder if there are any advantages over the Cocoa approach. Won't Carbon be ever removed completely?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Under the 68k Classic Mac OS runtime (e.g, before PowerPC *or* x86), C and Pascal used different calling conventions, so C applications had to declare the appropriate convention when calling into libraries using the Pascal conventions (including most of the operating system). The macro was implemented in contemporaneous compilers (e.g, MPW, Metrowerks, Think C).

In all newer runtimes, and in all modern compilers, the keyword is no longer recognized, so the `ConditionalMacros.h` header defines it away. There are a few comments in that file which may help explain a bit more -- read through it, if you're game.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't read the whole file. Now I understand why the Carbon hotkey API was used, however I can't understand one thing: when this code was written, the pascal convention was not being used anymore, right? So why did they put it there? :-P

Comment: Yeah, that's the one part that doesn't quite make sense. My best guess would be that the author had just been with Apple for a long time, and never got out of the habit of declaring functions as `pascal`!

Comment: Old habits die hard, a lot of code moved from 68k to a mixed 68k/PPC environment so the `pascal` keyword stuck around. Pascal could also used a `packed` directive to save memory which would require some fancy footwork in C to read.

Answer (score 4):

You have encountered a *calling convention*.

The pascal calling convention for the x86 is [described here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions#pascal).

It is very interesting that it was defined-away-to-nothing, which you notice means that it is not used anymore.  It was common in the old days in x86-land, especially in the Microsoft Windows APIs, because of the ability of the processor to remove parameters from the stack at the end of a call with its special `RET n` instruction.  Functions with the pascal calling convention were sometimes advantageous, because the caller wasn't explicity adjusting the stack pointer after each call returned.

If someone with more knowledge of *why* the macro still exists in the codebase, but is defined away comes along and gives you a better answer, I will happily withdraw this one.

Comment: Pretty interesting, I would never imagine this relates to the calling convention. If it applies to x86, it's not that old — but if I'm not mistaken in the time Intel Macs started to appear, Carbon was already being discouraged. So why this macro in a Carbon header… Yeah, let's wait if someone remembers these facts better, but please don't withdraw this answer :-)

Comment: I did a little googling with terms like CarbonLib, pascal, calling conventions, x86, Mac and so on.  Surprisingly very little is out there.  Chapter 6 of the O'Reilly Carbon book from 2001 is online; it shows `pascal` in the code examples but it is not explained in the text.  I think the real reason is for backward compatibility: the pascal convention was used in the old days when carbon was popular, so Apple #defined it to nothing for new apps so that old source would continue to run.  Just a hunch, but it makes sense to me.  Can anyone out there verify?

Comment: Thanks Ray. Yeah, it makes sense, the only thing that doesn't make sense is why did they used it in this code... Maybe a joke to check if people can see and understand it? :-)